# Using Python Requests for ASP.NET authentication

Tags: python, asp.net, authentication, python-requests

I think I'm on the right track for ASP.NET authentication. I'm trying to use requests to pass credentials to a website. Here are the headers and network info I pulled from chrome:

```
 Remote Address: REMOVED
Request URL: https://REMOVED/default.aspx

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found

Request Headers:

POST /default.aspx HTTP/1.1 
Host: REMOVED 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 928 
Cache-Control: max-age=0 
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 
Origin: https://REMOVED 
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Referer: https://REMOVED/default.aspx 
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch 
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=REMOVED; BIGipServerpool_REMOVED_dmz_80=REMOVED.REMOVED.0000; AUTHCDB=**REMOVED**

Form Data:
__EVENTTARGET:
__EVENTARGUMENT:
__VIEWSTATE: /wEP**REMAINDER REMOVED**
__EVENTVALIDATION: /wEd**REMAINDER REMOVED**
jsCheck:
ddlEngine:REMOVED:13008
Username:
Password:
btnLogin.x: 42
btnLogin.y: 9
btnLogin: Login

Response Headers:

Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 132
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 13 Jun 2014 00:59:13 GMT
Location: /Dashboard.aspx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: AUTHCDB=**REMOVED**; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Here is the script I wrote:

```
import requests

FORM_DATA = {
"__EVENTTARGET:":,
"__EVENTARGUMENT:",
"__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKMTA5NTA5ODU1MQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIGDxBkDxYFZgIBAgICAwIEF***REMAINDER REMOVED***",
"__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAAp4d3BHvSTs+Kv6cxGP3xEbBr8xrgRYad2tj4YCyRIw5qUAjimf****REMAINDER REMOVED****",
"jsCheck:",
"ddlEngine: REMOVED:13008",
"Username: ****",
"Password: ****",
"btnLogin.x: 42",
"btnLogin.y: 9",
"btnLogin: Login",
}

HEADER = {
"Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate,sdch",
"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8",
"Cache-Control":"max-age=0",
"Connection":"keep-alive",
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Host":"REMOVED",
"Origin":"REMOVED",
"Referer":"REMOVED",
"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36"
}

LOGIN_URL = "REMOVED"

#requests session to handle cookies. 
s = requests.Session()
#Send a POST request with the form data/header info
r = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=FORM_DATA, headers=HEADER)
if r.status_code == 302:
    print "Successfully logged in."
else:
    print "Error logging in."
```

Am I able to use Python Requests to log into a webpage that uses ASP.NET? If so, is this the correct way to pass the credentials into the website? For reference, the website I'm trying to log into is a company server monitor.

Comment: Can you post your final solution ? as I am also trying to login to asp.net website through python requests

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a similar issue was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996921/unable-to-login-to-asp-net-website-with-requests-module-of-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393219/python-requests-inserting-credentials-as-variables-in-form-data). I've been using RoboBrowser and it's made messing with ASPX so much simpler.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

login_url = 'http://example.com/Login.aspx'
username = 'JohnDoe'
password = 'passwd'

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
# This gets all the ASPX stuff, __VIEWSTATE and friends
browser.open(login_url)
signin = brower.get_form(id='aspnetForm')
signin["jsCheck"].value = ''
signin["ddlEngine"].value = "REMOVED:13008"
signin["Username"].value = username
signin["Password"].value = password
signin["btnLogin.x"].value = "42"
signin["btnLogin.y"].value = "9"
signin["btnLogin"].value = "Login"
browser.submit_form(signin)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm also working with some ASP.net pages right now, and being somewhat familiar with the requests module, I thought I'd try to help out a bit.

It is my understanding that requests supports basic authentication in this fashion:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

It could be the case that you'll need to import a different authentication library that works with ASP.net and plug that directly into the auth function of requests.

Hope this helps!