# Python Requests - Inserting credentials as variables in FORM_DATA

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to prompt the user for the username and password to login to a site. My plan is to use requests to send the POST data. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import requests
import getpass

uname = raw_input("Username: ")
passw = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Password: ")

FORM_DATA = {
"__EVENTTARGET:",
"__EVENTARGUMENT:",
"__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKMTA5NTA5ODU1MQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIGDxBkDxYFZgIBAgICAwIEF***REMAINDER REMOVED***",
"__EVENTVALIDATION:/wEdAAp4d3BHvSTs+Kv6cxGP3xEbBr8xrgRYad2tj4YCyRIw5qUAjimf****REMAINDER REMOVED****",
"jsCheck:",
"ddlEngine: REMOVED:13008",
"Username: %(uname)s" ,
"Password: %(passw)s",
"btnLogin.x: 42",
"btnLogin.y: 9",
"btnLogin: Login",
}

print FORM_DATA
```

This is obviously just a portion of the POST data, but I want to verify the credentials are passed first before moving forward. Using print does not show that the input has been inserted into the defined spots.

Comment: Are you *certain* these are headers, and not POST data? There is a **big** difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is the POST data the I got from the page after logging in. Original post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

POST data from a form is just a series of key-value pairs. Because all the keys are unique, just use a dictionary to represent these:

```
FORM_DATA = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': '',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT': '',
    '__VIEWSTATE': '/wEPDwUKMTA5NTA5ODU1MQ9kFgJmD2QWAgIGDxBkDxYFZgIBAgICAwIEF***REMAINDER REMOVED***',
    '__EVENTVALIDATION': '/wEdAAp4d3BHvSTs+Kv6cxGP3xEbBr8xrgRYad2tj4YCyRIw5qUAjimf****REMAINDER REMOVED****',
    'jsCheck': '',
    'ddlEngine': 'REMOVED:13008',
    'Username': uname,
    'Password': passw,
    'btnLogin.x': '42',
    'btnLogin.y': '9',
    'btnLogin': 'Login',
}
```

with empty values represented by empty strings.

The `btnLogin.x` and `btnLogin.y` keys are *usually* just ignored by a server; they communicate where you clicked on an image button. You can just set the username and password keys directly from the `uname` and `passw` variables you already set.

Then use this dictionary as the `data` keyword to the `requests.post()` call.

It *may* be the server expects a cookie back, set from the initial loading of the form. In that case a [Session object](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) and call `.get()` and `.post()` on that.

It *may* be that the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTVALIDATION` keys are dynamically set when the form is first generated, you would need to load it with `requests.get()`, parse the HTML (using, say, BeautifulSoup) and extract the form fields before sending.

Comment: `'%(uname)s'` should be just `uname`, and `'%(password)s'` should be just `password`.

Comment: @JonathanVillemaire-Krajden: ah, I actually missed those were already set. Corrected.