# Python - Sending __doPostBack (To join groups in Roblox)

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, dopostback, roblox

Roblox is a game, and you can also make groups (Like Clans in other games).

I am making a program that goes through these group pages, and checks to see if they have an owner. If there is not an owner, then join the group to become the owner.

I am doing this to collect some data from non-owned groups.

Lastly, I'd like it to leave the group once the data is collected.

Here is the "Join Group" button:

```
<div id="ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup" class="btn-neutral btn-large" onclick="__doPostBack('JoinGroupDiv', 'Click');" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    Join Group
</div>
```

Here is the snippet of code I've tried:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
Join_Group = dict('JoinGroupDiv', 'Click')
s.post('http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=40', data=Join_Group)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Group.py", line 18, in <module>
    Join_Group = dict('JoinGroupDiv', 'Click')
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm not supposed to be sending a Post request to the page, as to join the group, it does an onClick event.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my updated code:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
Join_Group = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup", "__EVENTARGUMENT":"JoinGroupDiv"}
s.post('http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=40', data=Join_Group)
```

But I don't quite know what to pass as the eventArguement. I don't get any errors, but when I load the page in Google Chrome it doesn't say I've tried to join.

**EDIT 2:**
I've also tried this:

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
Join_Group = {"__EVENTTARGET":"ctl00_cphRoblox_JoinGroup", "__EVENTARGUMENT":{"JoinGroupDiv","Click"}}
s.post('http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=40', data=Join_Group)
```

**EDIT 3:**
So what I have here is the updated Join_Group with all of the necessary fields, but not all of the information. I don't know where to get the information.

```
Join_Group = {"__EVENTTARGET":"JoinGroupDiv", "__EVENTARGUMENT":"Click", "__LASTFOCUS":"", "__VIEWSTATE":"a lot of mumbo jumbo", "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR":"It is 3D1CCC47 but that might change per post", "__EVENTVALIDATION":"some more mumbo jumbo"}
```

Here is a correct sample POST, but I don't know where it gets that information for `__VIEWSTATE`, `__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR`, and `__EVENTVALIDATION`.

```
__EVENTTARGET=JoinGroupDiv&__EVENTARGUMENT=Click&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=fM9l9%2BTw8z%2FRNbMArorqQ7HQ2w3soDiNp5gJOc5sNNQPEzEzApHiWLOHghGcAriUGv6pCVCi15my4%2BUxUozLVQyGx%2Fiq%2FU9BxRdN80kWJgMyiIyZYtSnfsvlFkqmrHaLIMNKag4eYwnKi5K3TP6JpP5xAxfNIOjekh6vpSa84YVL6eOwPsh5vqlHSN9VjFlwjA1r7AJVZkoeVliUz7vpK1f7DM6lDnOWBtFaAc66xxe2SIoLcjdMlfrVJpJADRjLTEfLp6PNARua3FLJKDezN7WOekGOlSIXHHrzAFlyMY0uZflFykzc9E3zE%2FldijdHWJnIoBVNW1c7fl2ehrbbv%2BAQWpeWqMagkuGNWOmFD6SHPixWLVNgNMlVLXrVKtLEMp3jmXLR40vqdv3bpCkJTLqA9M1XpKsBJlX5szlJlqJzYleD8NncUA8sO2sqiRhnk%2BZURIHV0EQRdPdzJIWMuENZZr%2FPKRl6MNekpZHOtF6wcWQYd4oRYptUjwzWQupbovVnaAyehNLMJbJi6sARkiXAQMC1kUyHpMQVrEdC69%2FNPEW8Cy6QIffUW1d0VBzVuK2hNJV1IgsbqEJZ56HXTtQCz4rJRlATwum2%2BcDS1ITfjA1JWuXwkbFON73TDPFsuz4fOhpVdmNvgN%2B%2F9h4YhmlxlsP3Ud%2BIfuPgzm4b%2FymVzdK%2FBOag7SjO9YRbqH6%2BrIXeXUmPf332sRw4twDy6LhqYxQmzBcr%2BLF4O0%2FTWW1N1pbusZ2p5nyVwaQEQd1FFeVTz5UXNvIUqA89x%2FWzrNHRUEdbR4ZQh5%2B9Eefd0IzIYza6TgRnWYknClVK1sq0qZ7bM1xhJfCsH3xCpWpVNqRqUZvOcWl8JH8aTrs2PhkkDU2%2Flto%2BlcsKG95lV06xukVyfa%2B2uzH%2FVp1Pph2jGLvMHTfLFdgt8jymryMt84jWtg8g%2F9N%2B%2Fb%2B69Pf4OuqLKx0md6Z6gOo4erBMvjrxSwWZxPBf%2BX674CclYnPpBsQjprvRMYGGGUtO957breZv5yQ0zWEB86BWHN6%2Fp6GJ%2Fb3TpeCEgEIKWB6VXxIt9EV7Ls9DrSb43eYSfUDKiBqpKcSD59g5W98rxrm%2FJhrzUnGQsVS4GRNR%2FquTJeWOc4NFIeyULqyLxLECaeXSPoqKe1ijkZc2cz%2FIDLNnmKY%2BMte7JslLswmWC469aL5%2BGMlgC%2FRJ%2BDhxZVbgOfAy7WZ4CoPtpoM2ixT5l5%2Ffg%2F1Z9jlRM4SAdU6XuC%2FnIJjYRBjZtA2IHE4xl87bgR8noUW%2FpMUmWeJrrScXuNpOKKhGoeM1XBg%2BiCZbFQ6oIihzGdqsvW4YQ3i%2BdzJEQvO%2FabotjD6zgekjvonlWOXTiSFXRS9h1JhyPFjMUdooDCkB7%2BtvuMj%2BUXUX2TccPtt%2BHdZpwtRVwzzf96J7bcs%2F1FaYhDsoJO01SqEtUAFWVqLO004kauPB6uJc%2FDSlBDqGI2hY02ORAl6BfyHVT4vxW8YDv55kD0R2hJhBtfhHsvQaEvrOR2BFHIB9hp5G2KW6zDuCWthVckhjUDsBDzOzc%2FDYtcBHCw8oWVXAbX%2BEjJNwHH2CVXVFO7HRSg3LEjRmqX1Hu72wXCp%2FlV3PCa%2FZcytUhuwMl%2B4PaqzD%2BQcTM0bm8JXylJAuksYMqQNkb9D%2BukLxyzADwfYFWy3aEJI1bVu0S0s6SJlLhGL1Z1E8x3sVh6vrMwYV6lZXzAU3BjYBgozfNvWpUDbM7bRJmEgBIgJFZJImFKs%2FwltOI6XACd1E%2BHQXchinr%2FHFYX2JW7uawkF0eJ7uNcYQ9O0pw9UNPWTOdVP855V3JIJZA0HvKt99Sn2Q%2FHgTWBAFmjefEI73B0wEGqIjPCTPJfljbcouvH6DfzttfGItUJ5g2lAN2H6lr%2F2UuRpjaJa3X924BF6WlIr%2FZ0JoAwxWvw1dvd00BCBamThc%2BK515yzwo5uYFKBlyt%2BQz9y%2FAf2mfRlI%2Bg%2BBV7b3LipC%2B66gfY6HJwOxNniy67qD1pkgKMRT6xeP8h86IOHUDyaG54RIMQAkYDSOyhUlKbMEsVbhq%2Fuqo9wvVq9djLSB%2BUcjpes%2Bfsn%2FyDdTl3nCWHd3xDC6MywPSvb%2F7pvhriQmpPjiXHhrvaMpWdecsXEF60kB3Hl5gm6klilE4ZkbcwakkSdGUVYn0b2mbM%2B7gq2lopcmTzAJuPAZI%2Fdp%2BnfT9mMywge6d1RP%2BCFBWCZdSXUjHHGvuWBPg2u8yfF7lQGOq7avsR%2BXZ2pi2afwwgzEyoHoxPYSfXn3J5%2FSkAINRE8rjbxK2n2qCRXSUlex1fp38OrPHK9TODFHPuq0whQQ2JYgq2IHXeUUiysJ1j5cub8JfZkoOEAm2TwnExVx9Fvvq3SadMWKKW8yOwZ6u%2BSLJUKu%2FtSzD6cXtiCbDpoZTe9LAeAgD%2FH9CDsvgX6sm6m441qf2glcOg01GsiLi%2BcVOGy14oT0I%2F0qtAjZS5qQskhMFNhrPudHgXgIw8%2BC81KK396oDN5JccahOO2Zuxkgiv3BtWO%2Fp8RBzrkPLR3hK2hj%2FVcSdwe0VUvq7%2FBNKyoRUsTN0tLWk6uvsce8P5avqG0VXXnUYuhvQTRBd88QACFMQW47kINvBq0N%2Ba8byLHlN8Kq%2BogTeBDuTn7CKOlOxi1ryxYm%2BUtzP4Ep0XBfrYba9Ztyp9L4Il0aNXElYudeV7i1NGwjh5FRgvYOPLQwTs7kHCIIUgpcYcX4oUUwdvyyZUDnzGPuWUhu1E0RELWiV89%2BJIiCrw4SKdohI86thnXhR9Ye%2FciOOjq8%2Foo0Vl9lq2Re2uJttZ9l99cCi54xFIPS1celZfZYKxR%2B2HTaB3EZ4z7%2FvdvQJ8BqXTWlfLTUh6M1wDJvZJPJkHBILh8sHMdew3NT2NSfF7dIzXIdg%2F8h5Pyy7NCQEXYn0nhlEecjuL3%2FOD4ccd4nq7FvoA9RcSLkpVg4OUy7KsQgfxwdp3KLrgJFowsqb5oN6zBojmWpFXhqaSSQFM3jsDQ6eCtxruTKTFqXc0eb23enSXNJoEIk%2BMQnwbycOYZomJ05Bi0dQrCEwMQ6jG%2Fq6pH2qfNiA5hoVHZww5miQHEHCT4vw0mTRky9d%2FuUNgjpZlK28iKV%2BT7i%2Ftq6UJ8ldEi%2FeFIpJUNi2tjQtQk2qrBw3L%2FN0Z7c%2BdkzqXxAByQCXuCA5v1Zt4yJKoC0763V6rrKU9JaIyeNAl4arqk%2BZ%2BQxfY6Ia6MmCpaGrzn4yHRnxnR52TEbn%2FhWM3LTzNeghmRphtKi4AereUSOJXbQOrdtVEG0uVF6ZNhX7DWYQ7BVI%2Bw5bN4Cp%2FBL9WxjD0s0WetzoRor0vL7IUHIzkoQkJHlBnCXXHh6Mif6Rzgm8O%2FfEgalGqhScqAwlXE5JYeZpm%2BusCO4gC0PE%2BSJzWQy63gHq5q3semEMn1cje95%2FIO5No09ZPoYkqAVd7XSBsVrYu%2BQhoGR8h95PcKeW7q2SVRanFCzC%2FhNALnQBh9qs78L23MiioERyE8D%2BnLi0K6l2Gba1BJ5tkbTaFynhuRWyq%2Bacvjbno5gPXVINSPoVf%2BbpZYSmgbZCAIrctXgInQuNBaWTzWICeJxKctTmaEIO6kXBB7y1p%2BzDpqVr4hjMkjZTS9mz8YLuU4eSAMhYD59GJZQi6mVkR1U8C9OsV6O%2BXOvnDQVWjrqQGIpVmfRv0B6sCtrBd%2BAX6N4TkaRfVehaW39%2BgnBB6SpTc0IZZ4apy%2BHXiOqVfLuABrL6JN6gH29V%2BRsd%2BybvouJRxdb47mxv7trl6JOwINUbERqsLQAPjrr54wBtS4LlRkvfBZpDAM7yCK%2FRpeT%2BjuC1X9i1p3CwL74V%2FN5Q5LxlA51Z9oxciOohCy4GkawbMSE8qor5%2BPwM4bNn%2FM%2FhgxmaOYRsoQZ4ZaEcRpAI5Vi4A3sIyYIdCbUvMmAKrEW%2FUeRhShapsCjLxcXeNuumWDCOHpJfVt3n8K0q6Ona%2FU4VkupnBbdK6Yo2%2FdBt64Zhmuzl3Pp9tnCmbYeuq%2BmR4B7PkCVNibRS0%2Fe8JI2S2mtSKb8XLVk%2BhmOXBxJ7sscsa%2FMjtWICOMVjg7fGYcwEXSUeJbVKMoCY1Jv7B6k4KV2sO9yruESkscm%2By3bV1rOFQgoQ2BFCS%2F1XwvFCWBoa4hoMgs1yVihXN7mRz61taqiPLqVoHNTSA4wOQtgS1xsYThYlZDpKyltNnFrs%2BB42yjByPn8qyR91eoobFYzjBvxnVrDg4DX58kJ2VumhFRe4NPg29seqk64Ps%2BbLUFDiCV39CVrsriWGR4G91xCeZpcv5NABou3M3RareJeoTTAmpBD3KUA3orZ8xRAUuFOkC9nDPJujH9nI117UMgScL9t9Rx7eB6l6jEt7KiMocEoRGHOMnSQJz28bbidFQWx0z0H67%2FcwOwSq0P71fDojxRc8Uhyk9yZKFfCiQ5HN6WnBS0u4O61hYDHO4oioPrFh4VvxdeYXf5Wz%2BDQFtdqUzYhC%2FlA%2FLWAWJF8WkQ%2BX7NEKUh3JO%2BxxFZJaJH28xgd4E5jnTT92orjalpTwTZ1y2Pm%2FsVUKyLm8oXhD9N2nTi%2FB2oey0H6Dn1Charhyc1MiS9dYLICym1zFBcTAQt6Our9D96Z20LRDi5UYci%2FxUDVJrwsBgREMxT4tXx41XsCJhkAxYvL1coY7HHmlgQUg6RDruY21h85VBJQeyNX0GkNUqXTaW5lTPRPflsIIbs80L0UX%2FZc6coyvlnWmkl3e93liSifT4eWW7AhhCAdXXZRKX2ZTzHKWnHzuXHoeP6MSHmSw6lA4Shi3VHv8TAmK4aumANtqASpxPw0I0rXy1U6dXW2UMj8FHEJP8pZ6BX5smKqMQaB6JuWP1pZCPgINg%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=3D1CCC47&__EVENTVALIDATION=qv5aJzTc3fM%2BcENN%2BTP2DgRs4ocXUM4qLJNP%2FtEv4q0xMardTbzlDm9uqRxoi%2BfRFn8e%2FC0PuVHiCvBR2xRuCXu%2BBQLORcJ%2BQ%2FANICydWIh6GamZbMbX0BfCN%2BuVKQqW8v1HzL9oN9IOmupGv9F%2BvyxGsToAR94w6szmvNNYvcmQKqcflo2K04UZh1lqzC7ScOHIhyMJb4xooM4oTg3qlmISKwYKDPhVgVgzU4zvzFueU2kToA0DykBBodt8%2BJcKHXbxt4UkL%2FBAZvHssrUeFA9OtAECcG4T3r68EB632IBprg8m9uiVX1wP%2BB8yQQdpQjBtYfT9rBHblz1HvaAu1mcRB0E%3D&ctl00%24cphRoblox%24GroupSearchBar%24SearchKeyword=Search+all+groups&ctl00%24cphRoblox%24rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane%24dlRolesetList=2343447&ctl00%24cphRoblox%24rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane%24RolesetCountHidden=2&ctl00%24cphRoblox%24rbxGroupRoleSetMembersPane%24currentRoleSetID=2343447&ctl00%24cphRoblox%24GroupWallPane%24GroupWallPager%24ctl01%24PageTextBox=1
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
s = requests.session()
login_data = dict(username='USERNAMEHERE', password='PASSWORDHERE')
s.post('https://www.roblox.com/newlogin', data=login_data)

page = s.get('http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=403577')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
VIEWSTATE=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATE")['value']
VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=soup.find(id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")['value']
EVENTVALIDATION=soup.find(id="__EVENTVALIDATION")['value']

Join_Group = dict(__EVENTTARGET="JoinGroupDiv", __EVENTARGUMENT="Click", __LASTFOCUS="", __VIEWSTATE=VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, __EVENTVALIDATION=EVENTVALIDATION)
join = s.post('http://www.roblox.com/Groups/Group.aspx?gid=403577', data=Join_Group)
print join
```

Comment: Those are being inserted into the page as hidden form fields by ASP.NET. You would need to read the page contents and extract those values from the form, then add them as fields on your POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is because this is not valid `dict` construction. You either need a literal (like `{'foo': 'bar'}`) or, if using the constructor, keyword arguments `dict(foo='bar')`.

You should do a POST as that's what `__doPostBack()` does - post back to the same page/URL that's been served, see [What is a postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251157/what-is-a-postback).

To determine what actually needs to be set for the POST, you should understand the `__doPostBack()` function. 
Those arguments are used to populate hidden form fields called `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`.

You can read an explanation about this here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667531/doPostBack-function

**Edit:** It's also worth noting that, when interacting with an application in this manner, you also need to be aware of any other state that's being managed and passed to the server. There are cookies, viewstate etc. to be considered. It's best to go through the process in a browser and inspect/record the requests with the developer tools to help you determine what data is required.

**Edit 2:** I see that Roblox has an API. You're much better off using this if/where possible rather than interacting with their UI.

See http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Web_APIs#Group_APIs

If this isn't letting you get access to a list of groups (I don't see a search here at a glance) then you might consider a hybrid approach.

**Edit 3:** For the scraping-type approach, you may want to consider Beautiful Soup for parsing the page/form and extracting the values being added by ASP.NET -

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: I've updated my question, adding the post arguments suggested.

Comment: I've added another try at this, still no avail.

Comment: I believe the event target and argument field values should match the arguments to `__doPostBack`, i.e. `JoinGroupDiv` and `Click`.

Comment: `Join_Group = {"JoinGroupDiv":"Click"}` didn't work either.

Comment: I'm thinking more like `Join_Group = {"__EVENTTARGET":"JoinGroupDiv", "__EVENTARGUMENT":"Click"}`

Comment: This is basically what the postback is doing, you'll likely want to check the response returned for more information. It will probably be a fully rendered HTML view but there may be some messages provided in the response.

Comment: It seems to be __EVENTTARGET that is causing a 500 response error. I can't figure out why though.

Comment: I wouldn't say that field is causing an error, it is required for the submission. Missing data such as "view state" is most likely the cause, which is an issue with interacting with a browser-based application in this way. It's likely you need to extract `__EVENTVALIDATION` and `__VIEWSTATE` hidden form field values and include those in your POST. Best to capture the browser request with browser developer tools while you manually join a group, but inspecting the request you can see what is required.

Comment: Using Fiddler4, I found out that there were more arguments to be sent, including __EVENTTARGET, __EVENTARGUMENT, __LASTFOCUS, __VIEWSTATE, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR, and __EVENTVALIDATION. It also is within a 302 result, which is a page redirect, so I think the `requests` response should be 302, not 200. I've updated my question if you are at all able to help with this, as I have no idea where most of the `POST` info comes from.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help, it works. I will post the final code. I ended up using Beautifulsoup too. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996921/unable-to-log-in-to-asp-net-website-with-requests-module-of-python) helped with gettning the POST variables too.

Comment: Oh, that's great. Yes, that post has got it all :)