# Using robobrowser on ASP.net website

Tags: python, html, asp.net, python-requests, robobrowser

I have been working on this for couple days now. Can not really find how to make this work. I am fairly new to aspx websites and fetching information out of them.

I am trying to login/authenticate on a website that uses aspx pages. So I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996921/unable-to-log-in-to-asp-net-website-with-requests-module-of-python) which really helped me get this in motion. (Last Answer)

Following those directions, I write:

```
url = "http://samplewebsite/Main/Index.aspx" # Logon page
username = "user"
password = "password"

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
# This retrieves __VIEWSTATE and friends
browser.open(url)
signin = browser.get_form(id='form1')
print(signin)
```

This is the outcome of that print statement:

```
<RoboForm __VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTE5ODM2NTU1MzJkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQlidG5TdWJtaXRriD1xvrfrHuJ/0xbQM08yEjyoUg==, __VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=E78488FE, adminid=, btnSubmit=, pswd=>
```

So it is obvious that I am retrieving the information correctly. Now I have 3 input fields:

```
adminid
btnSubmit
pswd
```

Which I can use in the following manner:

```
signin["adminid"].value = username
signin["pswd"].value = password
signin["btnSubmit"].value = "btnSubmit.x=29&btnSubmit.y=22"
```

My only problem is the last field `btnSubmit` which I do not know how to input a value since this is of the following type:

```
<input type="image" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" tabindex="3" src="../image/login_btn.gif" style="height:41px;width:57px;border-width:0px;" />
```

when I submit on the website, using the Chrome Tools I get the following outcome:

```
    __VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwULLTE5ODM2NTU1MzJkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBQlidG5TdWJtaXRriD1xvrfrHuJ/0xbQM08yEjyoUg==
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:E78488FE
adminid:user
btnSubmit.x:23
btnSubmit.y:15
pswd:password
```

Where basically the `x,y` positions are where I clicked on the page. Really do not know how to do this request through Python. Used [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an input object of type `image`, *two* form values are set, the button name plus `.x` for the first, and `.y` for the other.

However, pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a regular text input field will also submit a form, so you don't *have* to click on a submit button. I'd just leave the value empty altogether.

There is not much flexibility in the way robobrowser handles form submits, to avoid using the submit button you'd have to delete it from the form outright:

```
del signin.fields['btnSubmit']
```

before submitting.

If you *must* submit using the image button, then you'll have to teach Robobrowser how to handle that type; currently it has no handling for these. The following adds that:

```
from functools import wraps
from robobrowser.forms import form
from robobrowser.forms.fields import Submit, Input

class ImageSubmit(Submit):
    def serialize(self):
        return {self.name + '.x': '0', self.name + '.y': '0'}

def include_image_submit(parse_field):
    @wraps(parse_field)
    def wrapper(tag, tags):
        field = parse_field(tag, tags)
        if type(field) is Input:  # not a subclass, exactly this class
            if field._parsed.get('type') == 'image':
                field = ImageSubmit(field._parsed)
        return field
    return wrapper

form._parse_field = include_image_submit(form._parse_field)
```

at which point you can use `browser.submit_form(signin, signin['btnSubmit'])` to submit the form and the correct fields will be included.

I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser/pull/85) to the `robobrowser` project to add image submit support.

Comment: @Alexander: I don't know, does your browser end up on a different URL after submission? You didn't really give us more to work with to help you test.

Comment: Okay, So I have done everything above.  On the web browser, I start at this page: ```http://pagel.com/Login/VerifyAdmLogin.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2fpage.com%2fMain%2fIndex.aspx``` and once I login I end up at ```http://page.com/Main/Index.aspx```.  But I do no know how to check this within Python.

Comment: @Alexander: so what is `browser.url` after you submit the form?

Comment: The ```browser.url``` is the the initial one: ```http://page.com/Login/VerifyAdmLogin.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2fpage.com%2fMain%2fIndex.aspx``` which tells me that something did not go right and it did not login. Is that right?

Comment: @Alexander: I don't think it logged in in that case. Was that with or without the image submit? I suspect that ASP forms may be using some Javascript to add something to the form. Perhaps you need to switch to heavier artillery here and use [`requests-html`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html) to run the HTML of a page through a real browser. Note that that project doesn't have such nice form handling, however.

Comment: Indeed, after using the [code snippe](https://imgur.com/px7dK47)t as you gave me, it still redirects me to the login page. I checked the requests on Chrome Tools, do not see any JS input. Both JS that show up after pressing login, are GET methods, and none related to any form input. I will now read about the ```requests-html``` to see if I can make this happen

Comment: @Alexander you didn’t apply my supplied solution correctly. You didn’t use the `include_image_submit` decorator until after the firm has been parced, and it is the crucial link to have the new input type class I defined be actually used. Use it before creating the browser object.

Comment: it Worked!! I have no idea what this code does, I will have to go read about it to fully understand it. I appreciate all your help.