# python, authentication not recognised - urllib2, requests, asp.net

Tags: python, asp.net, passwords, python-requests, robobrowser

Though I'm not particularly advanced at any of this, I've had some past success in using urrlib2, requests and scrapy but this has me stumped. So after much searching and banging my head against the keyboard, I'll just go ahead and ask.

I'd like to get the html source code of a site but after using my username and password, I keep getting a page thrown back which says my username and password are wrong. They work fine in the browser, and once logged in the source code is readily available (via browser). But I can't seem to achieve the same result via python/terminal. I'll include some of my attempts (gleamed from the these helpful pages) below:

using urllib2:

```
req = Request(website, headers={ 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0' })
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (username, password)).replace('\n', '')
req.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
readweb = urlopen(req).read()
```

another version:

```
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, theurl, username, password)

authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)

pagehandle = opener.open(theurl)
return pagehandle.read()
```

and an attempt using requests:

```
r = requests.session()
try:
    r.post(theurl, data={'username' : 'username', 'password' : 'password', 'remember':'1'})
except:
    print('Sorry, Unable to...')
result = r.get(theurl)
return result.text
```

I've also tried to use scrapy, but regardless of which library I use it comes back with the html of a page which says my password/details are wrong. I'm guessing it's something to do with the headers/authorisation(?) I'm sending, but I'm not overly sure. Any help much appreciated, please let me know what other details I can update with (I've been up half the night with this, so if this post doesn't make sense please forgive me!)

EDIT:

Here's the traceback response to Prashant's answer below (minus the passwords etc.):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

> File "/Users/Hatsaw/newpy/pras.py", line 3, in 
>       r = requests.get(URL, auth=('username','password'))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 67, in get
>       return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/requests/api.py", line 53, in request
>       return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
>       resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
>       r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.9.0-py2.7.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 437, in send
>       raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='website', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /dashboard/ (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

EDIT:

Ok, I'm now using mechanize (recommended below), and here's what I'm getting back (not sure if this is another instance of my root problem or my inability with mechanize!):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

> File "/Users/Hatsaw/newpy/pras2.py", line 13, in 
>       browser.form['email'] = 'email address'
>     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 2780, in **setitem**
>     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 3101, in find_control
>     File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/mechanize/_form.py", line 3185, in _find_control
>   mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'email'

EDIT:

Still struggling with this, so here's a last ditch effort before time runs out on this project and I have to go in and get all the html manually! Fingers crossed..

Ok, so on the advice of barny, I'm back to using requests, and I'm attempting to provide the post with cookie information that I've gleamed from a successful browser login. I'm not certain I'm doing this correctly, but I'm using:

```
cookies = {'PHPSESSID':'5udcifi6p43ma3h1fnpfqghiu0'}
result = sess.get(the_url, cookies=cookies)
```

Now, at the moment, I'm getting an Internal Server Error response. After some research, aspnet forms seems to be the problem:

- [Sending an ASP.net POST with Python's Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975955/sending-an-asp-net-post-with-pythons-requests)
- [Using Python Requests for ASP.NET authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288915/using-python-requests-for-asp-net-authentication)

I just want to check that I'm not doing something wrong with requests first, then perhaps I'll explore BeautifulSoup/robobrowser as recommended by Martijn Pieters in the SO link above.

Here's what the form section of the html is asking:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" id="__VIEWSTATEFIELDCOUNT" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTkwNzg1NTQ3OA9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYGAgetc." />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE1" id="__VIEWSTATE1"     value="ZyBBIEhvbWUVIE5lZ290aWF0ZSBBZ3JlZW1lbnRzEiBSZetc." />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
    theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
    theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
    theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=t2SAOwDGkbrEfkmUaMOR9sPLXqgxfeenNayRja3DNK2R8JEcH-StTTuiaqXpzp--PAISn3vzVbWQ7biREwPkibCmbAE1&amp;t=635586505120000000" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=EL6tXtJfNfGSoQwhYtVnYEqw4oKvuwBBI4etc."     type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.');
//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=qCmNMcECQa0tfmMcZdwJeeOdcyetc." type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>

<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="FC5C7135" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdABB2xJRvPLCcg6GsBqRFCtw6Xg91QEu10etc." />
</div>
```

So. Some small questions.

- Does my 'user/pass' terminology have to match the source code i.e username = username or user?:
  I've lost where I found this in the html now, but I found 'ctl00$cphMain$tbUsername' and 'ctl00$cphMain$tbPassword'…
- Do I need to send the password and/or username as a base64.encodestring? 
  (I don't know if this is a problem, but the password contains chars such as !@$ etc.)
- Do I need to add ALL of the cookie fields I've found from the browser or just the PHPSESSID? Here are the fields I've got in the cookies:

ASP.NET_SessionId, CFID, CFTOKEN, __atuvc, __utma, __utmb, __utmc, __utmt, __utmz, BRO_CALLME, BRO_ID, BRO_LOGIN, BRO_MEMBER, BROAUTH, ISFULLMEMBER, phpMBLink, __CT_Data, WRUID

- There is the website (www.website.com), the login-page (www.website.com/login), and then the content (www.website.com/content). Am I correct in thinking I use the cookie from the (successfully logged in) login-page and 'send' it to the content page? Should I do this manually (enter field details from browser cookie information) or within the code (so, in code below I would use: cookies = r_login.cookies)?

Finally, here's the code I'm currently using that returns an Internal Server Error..:

```
import requests

the_url = 'the_url'
login = the_url + '/login'
content = the_url + '/content'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

sess = requests.Session()
sess.auth = ('username', 'password')
sess.get(the_url)

payload = {'ctl00$cphMain$tbUsername': username, 'ctl00$cphMain$tbPassword': password}
r_login = sess.post(login, data=payload)

cookies = {'PHPSESSID':'5udcifi6p43ma3h1fnpfqghiu0', 'ASP.NET_SessionId':'aspnet', 'BRO_LOGIN':'bro_login'}
r_data = s.get(content, cookies=cookies, data=payload)

print r_data.text
```

Apologies, this has gotten rather long now, if I need to split it up over several posts please let me know - what I assumed was a simple question at the outset has mutated into something else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victory!

Ok, with thanks to Prashant and barny for their responses, and a big thanks to Martijn Pieters via this post:
[Sending an ASP.net POST with Python's Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975955/sending-an-asp-net-post-with-pythons-requests)

I've found my salvation to be
[robobot](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Here's the code:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

the_url = 'the_url'
login = the_url + '/login'
content = the_url + '/content'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

browser = RoboBrowser(parser='lxml')

browser.open(login)
form = browser.get_forms()  

# You can use '.get_form()' for a specific form but I'm finding it easier to 
# using '.get_forms()' to get all the forms and then I'm just interested 
# in the first one:

form = form[0]
print form     # this will give you the information you need to 
               # now enter your password details:   

form['the_user'].value = username
form['the_pass'].value = password

browser.submit_form(form)

# and then because I'm after the html of certain content pages:

browser.open(content)
source = str(browser.parsed)
return source
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
URL = "http://www.facebook.com'
r = requests.get(URL, auth=('username','password'))
source = r.text
print source
```

-----CHANGE-----

```
import mechanize
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_handle_robots(False)
cookies = mechanize.CookieJar()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookies)
browser.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41 Safari/534.7')]
browser.set_handle_refresh(False)

url = 'http://www.facebook.com/login.php'
self.browser.open(url)
self.browser.select_form(nr = 0)       #This is login-password form -> nr = number = 0
self.browser.form['email'] = YourLogin
self.browser.form['pass'] = YourPassw
response = self.browser.submit()
print response.read()
```

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31091775/5313264)

Comment: Cool, I'd not heard of mechanize, I've downloaded it now and given that a try (I'm assuming the second half of your code needs to go inside a function? or class?) it's not printing any response as yet, but I'll bash away at it for a while see what I can do, cheers Prashant, I'll update soon

Comment: Ok, so I think I've got mechanize running okay, but I'm getting an error (see above) - does this have something to do with the form number you mentioned? I've left it at 0.

Comment: log in on the website, look at your cookies and copy the value of PHPSESSID.
then paste it in: cookie = in the config.ini and set keepsignedin = 1

Comment: Hi Prashant, thanks for your help in this, I've now got the PHPSESSID but I'm a little confused where to paste it etc. - is the 'config.ini' a mechanize thing? or a web-browser thing? I've searched, but still unsure..

Comment: If you use a requests session, it will hold the cookie and automatically provide it on subsequent requests.

Comment: @barny is right , If you're getting setitem error scroll up their must be **IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ** over you'll find path of config.ini further is self explanatory

Comment: Ok, to be clear, can one of you please provide some code as an example? I think I understand what barny is saying but I'm not getting any IOError, Pras...(please see traceback above). I'm now searching how to add a cookie to a request.. Sorry to be a pain, but it sounds like we're close now!

Comment: mac osx10.8, python 2.7

Comment: Could you perhaps update your original requests code with the additional cookie information? I'm guessing I use something like 'requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict'?

Comment: Did that solved your problem, or another approach is required.

Comment: Hi Prashant, no, I'm still struggling with it. Providing I'm adding cookies correctly (I'm not convinced I am), I'm getting an Internal Server Error. I think it has something to do with aspnet forms? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975955/sending-an-asp-net-post-with-pythons-requests, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288915/using-python-requests-for-asp-net-authentication